# A function can take another function as one of its arguments

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I wrote the following code in playground and try to learn from [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-ID1) function & classes.
Here is my code..

```
func hasAnyMatches(list: [Int], condition: (Int) -> Bool) -> Bool {
    for item in list {
        if condition(item) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
func lessThanTen(number: Int) -> Bool {
    return number < 10
}
var numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]
hasAnyMatches(numbers, condition: lessThanTen)
```

How can I directly pass the different condition?
can I write like that..

```
hasAnyMatches(numbers, condition: { $0 < 10 })
```

Actually this function return true/false, but when I write like that so in play ground behalf of this line o/p: (4 times)
So what happen when I'm write like that.

And give me solution to direct pass the condition in hasAnyMatches() func.

Answer (score 1):

The way you wrote it was fine! You're just missing the first argument label in the call. It should be:

```
hasAnyMatches(list: numbers, condition: { $0 < 10 })
```

Comment: Ya I write like that but In playground o/p: true/false not display like it happen in original code

Comment: It won't - that's just because of the way playgrounds work. If the code still works correctly, then that doesn't matter.

Comment: @SørenMortensen If you want the playground to output true/false did my answer help you?

Comment: @Sweeper I'm not really sure what you're asking me... I'm not the OP, and I posted my answer before yours

Comment: @SørenMortensen oops. I tagged the wrong person. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

When you write this:

```
hasAnyMatches(numbers, condition: { $0 < 10 })
```

The playground says "(4 times)". This is because the closure `{ $0 < 10 }` is executed four times, one time on each item in `numbers`.

To get it to show the return value of the `hasAnyMatches` function, there are a few ways to do this.

- You can just make `{$0 < 10}` be on its own line:

  ```
  hasAnyMatches(list: numbers, condition: // shows true on this line
      {$0 < 10} // shows (4 times) on this line
  )
  ```
- You can store the result into a variable, then get the value of the variable:

  ```
  let val = hasAnyMatches(list: numbers, condition: {$0 < 10})
  val // shows true on this line
  ```

Answer (score 1):

hasAnyMatches function takes the list of numbers and the condition closure so you can pass any closure which takes a Int and returns bool

```
let numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]
let lessThan: (Int) -> Bool = { $0 < 10 }
let match = hasAnyMatches(list: numbers, condition: lessThan)
print(match)
```

Another way to write the same thing would be to use [filters](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/) which iterates over a collection and return an Array containing only those elements that match an include condition. main advantage of using filter is its inbuilt and you don't need separate hasAnyMatches function to check the condition

```
let numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]
let match = numbers.filter ({ $0 < 10 }).count > 0
print(match)
```